# Windows SVN browser without shell integration?

Tags: svn

Can anyone recommend a Windows SVN repository browser without shell integration?

I need it to be portable (carry with me on a flash drive), therefore without an installation process. This rules out TortoiseSVN.

My repositories are local, so I need a tool that can access a file repository.

Comment: I don't understand "I need it to be portable, therefore without an installation process".  "Portable" means it runs on many platforms, and this is often achieved by taking certain steps during the installation process.  Are you defining "portable" to mean something else?

Comment: I think by portable means he can carry it around on a flash drive or any other portable device :)

Comment: Portable means that the installation of the software and the settings it uses is not tied to the operating system. The software can be run from a portable thumb-drive where it is self-contained and doesn't read or write any of it's settings to the Windows Registry, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go to http://portableapps.com/node/13470  you will find exactly what you are looking for - RapidSVN Portable. Be sure to use the PAF installer.

Comment: No problem. I use it myself, so that's how I was able to recommend it so easily.

Comment: Too bad RapidSVN doesn't support SSH.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be *really* portable then your best bet is to get use to using the Subversion command line tools. You can do everything you'll need to with them and they'll be the same on every platform that subversion is available before.

Answer (score 2):

http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Subcommander](http://subcommander.tigris.org/). Although it is delivered in installer, I'm sure you can rip the binaries from installed version, or take the sources and compile it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe PySVN Work Bench is what you are looking for: http://pysvn.tigris.org

Answer (score 0):

With portable you mean that you can run it from a USB drive?

The other TortoiseSVN-like program that I know of on Windows is SmartSVN, but i) I don't know if you can install it on a thumb drive, and ii) I'm not entirely sure if it's freeware or not (there's definitely a free trial option).

One alternative that should work from a thumb drive is installing Cygwin and using the svn command line tool. Obviously you're not getting a graphical tool in this case, but it should run quite happily from a thumb drive.

Comment: You don't need Cygwin to run snv command line client, there are  native Win32 binaries of it

Answer (score 0):

[SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/):

- written in java ( can eat lot's of memory, but gives consistent ui on win/mac/linux)
- shell integration is optional
- free foundation edition (even for commercial use)

Comment: I tried SmartSVN and found 2 issues:

1) I can't get a portable Java installation to work (although apparently this is possible)

2) SmartSVN can't browse a repository using the file:// protocol.